# SQOOP:customize input data before exporting into postgress DB

Tags: hive, hadoop2, sqoop, sqoop2

I want  to export input data from hdfs into postgress db through sqoop.
I am able to achieve this when my input data is in proper format with postgress table.

But i want to perform some operation on my input data before exporting it into db like lets say i want to add some no to each value before i put it.

so,does sqoop provides any such apis to peform this..

sqoop version:1.4.6

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop doesnt support any operations while exporting. Its just take export-dir as input. You can use pig/hive to perform some operations for imported data and output dataset can be exported back to your postgress db.